# Regular expressions for password

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regular expression for password which must have

1. a minimum of 7 characters
2. with at least 1 number and 1 alphabet within that  first 7 characters.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: ((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d))[a-z0-9]{7,} but this is taking even if it han only alphabets in first 7 character

Answer (score 0):

Since the characters after the first 7 do not require checking, you can run a regex just on the first 7:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z]).{7}$/.test(password.substring(0,8))
```

- ^ starts with
- (?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z]) positive lookahead: must contain at least one of these characters
- .{7} match exactly 7 characters

Comment: hi, but this is taking even if all 7 are alphabets.